# Missing 'in' after variable in foreach loop

Tags: asp.net, powershell, iis, foreach, application-pool

I am trying to execute below powershell script to get application pool status.But i am getting below error. Can someone please help me here what i am missing??

Code:

```
import-module webadministration
$applicationPools = Get-ChildItem IIS:\AppPools
ForEach ($_.name in $applicationPools)
{
$appPool = $_.name
$appmemversion = get-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\$appPool" ManagedRuntimeVersion.value
$appmem = get-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\$appPool" recycling.periodicrestart.privateMemory.value
$apptimeinv = get-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\$appPool" recycling.periodicRestart.time | select-object value
$appsettime = get-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\$appPool" Recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.collection[0].value | select-object value 
Write-Output "$appPool,$appmemversion,$appmem,$apptimeinv,$appsettime," 
}
```

Error:

```
+ ForEach ($_.name in $applicationPools)
+            ~
Missing 'in' after variable in foreach loop.
At C:\Users\JoyMathew\Desktop\App.ps1:9 char:38
+ ForEach ($_.name in $applicationPools)
+                                      ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingInInForeach
```

Regads,
Joy

Comment: $_ is used during pipelines... you've separated the $application pools from the foreach loop so if you change the $_.name to a variable name like $pool that should fix your issue.

Comment: @thomschumacher You should make that an answer, and give a quick example of corrected code.

Comment: I tried wrapping $($_.name) , but i am still getting same error.

Comment: I am able to run the same code on other systems. but facing this issue on some of the application servers.

Comment: the first part in parentheses needs to be the name of a variable, not the name of a property of $_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import-module webadministration
$applicationPools = Get-ChildItem IIS:\AppPools
ForEach ($Name in $applicationPools)
{
    $appPool = $Name
    $appmemversion = get-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\$appPool" ManagedRuntimeVersion.value
    $appmem = get-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\$appPool" recycling.periodicrestart.privateMemory.value
    $apptimeinv = get-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\$appPool" recycling.periodicRestart.time | select-object value
    $appsettime = get-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\$appPool" Recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.collection[0].value | select-object value 
    Write-Output "$appPool,$appmemversion,$appmem,$apptimeinv,$appsettime," 
}

# OR

import-module webadministration
$applicationPools = Get-ChildItem IIS:\AppPools
$applicationPools | ForEach-Object {
    $appPool = $_.name
    $appmemversion = get-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\$appPool" ManagedRuntimeVersion.value
    $appmem = get-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\$appPool" recycling.periodicrestart.privateMemory.value
    $apptimeinv = get-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\$appPool" recycling.periodicRestart.time | select-object value
    $appsettime = get-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\$appPool" Recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.collection[0].value | select-object value 
    Write-Output "$appPool,$appmemversion,$appmem,$apptimeinv,$appsettime," 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is what I meant:

```
import-module webadministration
$applicationPools = Get-ChildItem IIS:\AppPools
ForEach ($pool in $applicationPools)
{
$appPool = $pool.name
$appmemversion = (get-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\$appPool").ManagedRuntimeVersion.value
$appmem = (get-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\$appPool").recycling.periodicrestart.privateMemory.value
$apptimeinv = (get-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\$appPool").recycling.periodicRestart.time # | select-object value
$appsettime = (get-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\$appPool").Recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.collection[0].value #| select-object value 
Write-Output "$appPool,$appmemversion,$appmem,$apptimeinv,$appsettime," 
}
```

I took your select out by using the .dotted not notation for the object that Get-ItemProperty is returning ... That way if one of the items is null you'll get null in your output.

Comment: glad I could help